# What is the width of fixed-width integers in bash?

Tags: bash, limit

[Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) says:

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow,
>   though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error.

Example:

```
$ echo $(( 1 << 32 ))
4294967296
$ echo $(( (1 << 64) - 1 ))
0
```

What are integer limits in shell arithmetic in bash?

[@rici pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26123955/4279) that [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) guarantees **signed long** integer range (as defined by ISO C):

```
-2**31+1 to +2**31-1
```

[@John Zwinck pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26121803/4279) that [`bash` source code indicates that `intmax_t` is used](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/expr.c#n22):

> All arithmetic is done as `intmax_t` integers with no checking for overflow

Does bash guarantee **in its documentation** that it uses `intmax_t` or some other C type for integers?

Comment: I don't think subtracting 1 after it has overflown (!) will help :-)   Try echo $(( (1 << 63) - 1 ))... 9223372036854775807

Comment: @MarkSetchell: the point is that `1 << 64` overflows on my machine. The result doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I had visions of you doing a binary search to find the shift that didn't overflow... <<48, <<56,<<60,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bash does not document the precise size of integers, and the size may vary from platform to platform.**

However, it does make an attempt to conform to Posix, which specifies that arithmetic expansion uses signed long arithmetic, which must be at least 32 bits including the sign bit.

Posix does not require integer arithmetic to be modulo 2<sup>k</sup> for any value of `k` [but see Note 1], although `bash` on common platforms will do so, and it particularly does not guarantee that arithmetic operators will behave exactly as though the values were signed longs. Posix even allows the simulation of integer arithmetic with floating point, provided that the floating point values have sufficient precision:

> As an extension, the shell may recognize arithmetic expressions beyond those listed. The shell may use a signed integer type with a rank larger than the rank of signed long. The shell may use a real-floating type instead of signed long as long as it does not affect the results in cases where there is no overflow. (XSH §2.6.4)

That would permit the use of IEEE-754 floating point doubles (53 bits of precision) on a platform where `long` was only 32 bits, for example. While `bash` does not do so -- as documented, `bash` uses a fixed-width integer datatype -- other shell implementations might, and portable code should not make assumptions.

---

**Notes:**

1. Posix generally defers to the ISO C standard, but there are a number of places where Posix adds an additional constraint, some of which are marked as extensions (<kbd>CX</kbd>):

   > POSIX.1-2008 acts in part as a profile of the ISO C standard, and it may choose to further constrain behaviors allowed to vary by the ISO C standard. Such limitations and other compatible differences are not considered conflicts, even if a CX mark is missing. The markings are for information only.

   One of these additional constraints is the existence of exact-width integer types. Standard C requires the types `int_{least,fast}{8,16,32,64}_t` and their unsigned analogues. It does not require the exact-width types, such as `int32_t`, unless some integer type qualifies. An exact-width type must have exactly the number of bits indicated in its name (i.e. no padding bits) and must have 2's-complement representation. So `INT32_MIN`, if it is defined, must be exactly -2<sup>31</sup> (§7.20.2.1).

   However, Posix *does* require the exact-width types `int{8,16,32}_t` (as well as the unsigned analogues), and also `int64_t` if such a type is provided by the implementation. In particular, `int64_t` is required if the "implementation supports the `_POSIX_V7_LP64_OFF64` programming environment and the application is being built in the `_POSIX_V7_LP64_OFF64` programming environment." (XBD, §13, `stdint.h`) (These requirements are marked as <kbd>CX</kbd>.)

   Despite the fact that `int32_t` must exist, and therefore there must be some 2's complement type available, there is still no guarantee that `signed long` is 2's-complement, and even if it is, there is no guarantee that integer overflow wraps around rather than, for example, trapping.

   Most relevant to the original question, though, is the fact that even if `signed long` is the same type as `int64_t` and even if signed integer overflow wraps around, the shell is not under any obligation to actually use `signed long` for arithmetic expansion. It could use any datatype "as long as it does not affect the results in cases where there is no overflow." (XSH, §2.6.4)

Comment: +1 for mentioning **signed long** limit for POSIX shell. [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) explicitly defers to ISO C standard for integer arithmetic (same as **signed long** ISO C). It is ISO C that doesn't require module 2**k arithmetic, not posix.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Posix was free to require 2s-complement arithmetic. It requires 8-bit bytes, for example, so it is quite capable of requiring things which standard C does not. So I stand by my statement that Posix doesn't require 2s-complement. But the more important point is the next sentence: Posix doesn't require the shell to even follow the behaviour of signed longs on that platform, because it (explicitly) allows the use of floating-point where that has at least as much precision as a signed long.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Added a bit of bold (without changing any text) in an attempt to demonstrate that this excessively long post includes an answer to the question "Does bash guarantee in its documentation ..." (i.e. "No, there is no guarantee.") I verified my reading of the manual by grepping bashref.texi for a few key words, so I'm prepared to go out on a limb with a definite "No." Of course, that's true as of today (v4.3.25); the documentation could change at any moment.

Comment: the text in your answer contradict the documentation, the quote says: *"The shell may use a real-floating type instead of signed long as long as it does not affect the results in cases where there is no overflow."* -- it implies that we can always assume 'signed long' semantics (the results are guaranteed to be the same whatever the type if there is no overflow).

Answer (score 3):

Bash uses `intmax_t` in its C implementation of arithmetic.  You can see it here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-30/bash/expr.c

This means it will be the "largest" integer type on your platform.  Keep in mind that some platforms have "even larger" integers, e.g. 128 bit ints on some 64 bit platforms, but those "extraordinary" types are not included here, so most systems will see Bash using 32 or 64 bit math for now.

Comment: [the current source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/expr.c#n22) also confirms that `intmax_t` is used. Is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: I haven't found any place where it's in the (non-source code) documentation.  Probably it was considered an implementation detail somehow.  I don't think this is all that important though because it's very clearly documented in the source code itself; I suppose you could submit a documentation patch.