# How to find range of various datatypes in bash?

Tags: bash

i have to find the range of datatypes for example in c++ :

`int`,`unsigned int`,`double`,`char`....

and we know the range and memory size of this variables in c++ ,bu  i want to know how can i define this  ranges in bash script language,and how can i know the type of data's in bash script, i mean which of the int,double,char,... we can define in bash script and how can i explain this , and get the result ,i want to know exactly type of data's and range of that data's and find out how much memory reserved for example int == 4 byte in c++, but i want to know this size in bash script

Comment: You would have to do what autoconf-generated `./configure` scripts do, for example.  This would mean compiling a small C++ program, running it, and capturing the output.

Comment: Might be easiest just to use autoconf, rather than trying to reimplement it (and risking doing so badly).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in c++ int get 4 byte in memory and typical range 0-225 , ok? if i know to define an int in bash script how much memory or typical range that will have in bash script?

Comment: If you want to know the range of bash native integers, rather than knowing the C datatype sizes in bash, someone else has asked and answered that already.

Comment: ...see for instance  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121659/what-is-the-width-of-fixed-width-integers-in-bash; there's another question on the topic as well.

Comment: @kookoorere _"how much memory or typical range that will have in bash script?"_ Variables used in bash are working completely different than in c++. Consider those just stored as textual key/value pairs. As soon you're doing any numeric operations with them, bash will turn them into numeric values internally.

Comment: Short answer: Bash doesn't have "various datatypes"; it has integers, and it has strings, and the other types (associative arrays, integer-indexed arrays, namevars) are non-numeric, so this question doesn't apply. The integers are already asked and answered in a different question, so closing this as duplicate.

Comment: And here I just finished writing [this beauty](http://pastebin.com/SnYQZYVU)...

Comment: @cdhowie, that's a good enough answer that I'm retracting my close vote -- it makes the point succinctly and well that there's room for an answer here that wouldn't be applicable there.

Comment: @cdhowie, ...though I'd suggest testing `intmax_t`, since that's what bash's native types use, rather than char/short/etc (given the OP's clarification of goals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types for Bash are different from those in C++, but on the off-chance that someone stumbles onto this question looking for a way to obtain the size, minimum value, and maximum value for C++ data types from a Bash script, here is one way this could be done:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Terminate script if any command fails.
set -e

# Make temporary directory.
mydir=$(mktemp -dt "$0XXXX")

# Set trap to remove the temp directory when we exit.
function cleanup {
    rm -fr "$mydir"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

# Write source code for program that will output information about various types.
cat > "$mydir/source.cpp" <<SOURCE
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
void write_type_info()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << std::endl
              << std::numeric_limits<T>::min() << std::endl
              << std::numeric_limits<T>::max() << std::endl;
}

template <>
void write_type_info<char>()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(char) << std::endl
              << static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<char>::min()) << std::endl
              << static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<char>::max()) << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
    write_type_info<intmax_t>();
    write_type_info<char>();
    write_type_info<short>();

    return 0;
}

SOURCE

# Compile this code
g++ -std=c++11 -o "$mydir/program" "$mydir/source.cpp"

# Run it, capturing the output in an array
output=($("$mydir/program"))

echo Size of intmax_t: ${output[0]}
echo Min value of intmax_t: ${output[1]}
echo Max value of intmax_t: ${output[2]}
echo Size of char: ${output[3]}
echo Min value of char: ${output[4]}
echo Max value of char: ${output[5]}
echo Size of short: ${output[6]}
echo Min value of short: ${output[7]}
echo Max value of short: ${output[8]}
```

The first set of outputs from this script -- for `intmax_t` -- are the limits relevant for native integer math in bash.

Example output, which may differ depending on compiler, operating system, and/or architecture:

```
Size of intmax_t: 8
Min value of intmax_t: -9223372036854775808
Max value of intmax_t: 9223372036854775807
Size of char: 1
Min value of char: -128
Max value of char: 127
Size of short: 2
Min value of short: -32768
Max value of short: 32767
```

Comment: Consider `mapfile -t output < <("$mydir/program")` instead of `output=( $("$mydir/program") )` -- the difference isn't exceptionally important here, where all content is integers, but if output could include wildcard or glob characters, it becomes a significant difference in practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added support for `intmax_t` but note that this requires `<cstdint>` and therefore C++11 support.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose the more portable route would be to use C rather than C++.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Probably. But then I can't use my fancy templates. D: At any rate, this is a good starting point for someone who wants this functionality.

Comment: ...though in this particular case, perhaps preprocessor macros would do the job just as well, other than aesthetics. :)

Comment: ...well, actually, no, _not_ as well; would have to hardcode the constants for min and max for each, whereas with C++ you get those free.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's worth noting that the question specifically mentions C++ and not C.  While I know that on most systems the primitive data types available in C have the same properties as those in C++, it's not technically guaranteed, so you could make the argument that an answer using C may not be valid.